# How to do regression discontinuity on panel data in R?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, panel-data, factor-analysis

I am trying to analyze the impact of reopenings on consumer spending in American counties.

I have a panel data containing information about the level of spending, income of the county and the state of reopening in the county (which is a factor variable between 0 and 3
0 - no measures
1 - recommend not leaving house
2 - require not leaving house with exceptions for daily exercise, grocery shopping, and 'essential' trips
3 - require not leaving house with minimal exceptions).

I would like to get the average effect of the change in the respective levels of reopening on the level of spending and whether the effects vary between counties.

What I want to get to know from the regression is something like: A change from 2 to 1 in reopening level is associated with a 25 % decrease in spending and the percentage decrease is 1% bigger for $1000 increase in the median household income of the county.

I was thinking of using `plm` within model; something like

```
regression <- plm(data, spending ~ factor(reopening_level) * household_income, model = "within")
```

but by using the within model I lose the ability to find out how the household income influenced the spending, as it is constant on the county level.

Perhaps I could use the `rdd` package, but I am unsure about how to run a regression on panel data in that package.